# How to decrease session time in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

i have write this code in app/Config/core.php file of cakephp to timeout in 1 minute

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'php',
        'timeout' => 1,
        'autoRegenerate' => true
));
```

but this code not work

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `'php'` `defaults`, the time out is actually taken from the `session.cookie_lifetime` directive in `php.ini`. Either change the value in the `php.ini` configuration for your php or change the configuration like this:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'autoRegenerate' => true,
    'ini' => array('session.cookie_lifetime' => $timeInSeconds)
));
```